# How to crop image in different shapes

Tags: java, image, crop

I try to get a subImage from the given image as shown below: [image]
I know how to crop in rectangular shape like this

```
image = image.getSubImage(x, y, width, height);
```

but by using this method it is not possible for me to get different shape image from a given image, if anyone has suggestion can show me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the Graphics class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/clipping.html